# How using Lite-Objects by using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have a class/table named **Project** with 100 properties. The first step in my app is to select a project from a grid which contains all availalbe projects.
It's obviously that loading all full projects only for that grid is too much.

Without an ORM I would create a **SQL-View** from project with five columns.

What is the common way when using EntityFramework to load such a **ProjectLite**-object?

Comment: select a few columns or create a view and run query for this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own class and project the results into there. For example:

```
public class LargeClass
{
    public string Thing1 { get; set; }
    public string Thing2 { get; set; }
    //snip
    public string Thing100 { get; set; }
}

public class SmallClass
{
    public string Thing1 { get; set; }
    public string Thing50 { get; set; }
    public string Thing100 { get; set; }
}
```

And now do this:

```
var results = context.LargeClasses
    .Select(x => new SmallClass
    {
        Thing1 = x.Thing1,
        Thing1 = x.Thing50,
        Thing1 = x.Thing100
    });
```

This will run SQL equivalent to this:

```
SELECT
    [c].[Thing1] AS [Thing1], 
    [c].[Thing50] AS [Thing50], 
    [c].[Thing100] AS [Thing100]
    FROM [dbo].[LargeClasses] AS [c]
```

Comment: Cool. That Looks very comfortable! I didn't no that linq's select will be translated to SQL.

Comment: If you didn't know that, then I strongly recommend you learn some of the fundamentals of Entity Framework then. I suspect there's a lot of basics that will be helpful for you when writing your queries.